# Wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) after updating from Rails 3.0.3 to Rails 3.0.10 to Rails 3.2.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I recently upgraded my Rails web app from 3.0.3 to 3.0.10. And got the Wrong Number of arguments (1 for 0) error. I figured I would throw a "hail Mary" pass and hope that upgrading to Rails 3.2.8 would make things better. Not! :-)

I am stumped as to what could have caused this and I am a novice and not able to decipher the stack trace. Here is my stack trace. I'd appreciate some help.

I branched off of my master, so I can always start from scratch again, but I've tried twice so far with the same results.

```
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `display'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `send_action'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `process_action'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:403:in `_run__1653335973__process_action__374356064__callbacks'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `send'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `send'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/cells-3.8.6/lib/cell/rendering.rb:7:in `render_state'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/cells-3.8.6/lib/cell/caching.rb:83:in `render_state'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/cells-3.8.6/lib/cell/rendering.rb:105:in `render_cell_state'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/cells-3.8.6/lib/cell/rack.rb:27:in `render_cell_state'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/cells-3.8.6/lib/cell/rendering.rb:100:in `render_cell_for'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/cells-3.8.6/lib/cells/rails.rb:53:in `render_cell'
app/views/home/index.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_home_index_html_erb__617638568_2260825620'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `send'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `render'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:125:in `instrument'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:47:in `render_template'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:46:in `render_template'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `render_with_layout'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:45:in `render_template'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:18:in `render'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:36:in `render_template'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:17:in `render'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:110:in `_render_template'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:225:in `_render_template'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:103:in `render_to_body'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:28:in `render_to_body'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal/compatibility.rb:50:in `render_to_body'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:88:in `render'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `ms'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `ms'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:83:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:24:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:39:in `render'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `process_action'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:414:in `_run__1183885179__process_action__918435846__callbacks'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `send'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `send'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `action'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `call'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:600:in `call'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/warden-1.2.1/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `call'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/warden-1.2.1/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/warden-1.2.1/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `context'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200:in `call'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:339:in `call'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:473:in `call'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `call'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__1199251717__call__4__callbacks'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `send'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `send'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:104:in `service'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:65:in `run'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in `start_thread'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start_thread'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:95:in `start'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `each'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `start'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:23:in `start'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:82:in `start'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:13:in `run'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:265:in `start'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:55
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
vendor/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:50
script/rails:6:in `require'
script/rails:6
```

Here is the entire error message:

[image: Error message]

Comment: Hi, Adam. Down a little lower I mention the "hail Mary" pass to 3.2.8. I should have been more clear. Also, I am running ruby 1.8.7. I'm wondering if that might need to be updated to ruby 1.9.2.

Comment: When to you get this error message? Is this the whole error message (suspect not, can't see which method actually is complaining)? What's the content of `app/views/home/index.html.erb`?

Comment: I've attached a screen shot of the error. As you can see there is no specific method that is being cited as the cause of the error. This is what is leaving me baffled.

Comment: What's in your `home#index` controller method?

Comment: `class HomeController < ApplicationController
  #SMC - This specifies the layout to use: views/layouts/index.html.erb
  layout 'home'
  
  def index
  end
  
end`

Comment: Please post your layout file (usually application.html.erb) and your ApplicationController. Preferrably use gist.github.com

Comment: Thanks, Jesper. Here is my layout: http://gist.github.com/3935260. It should be noted that similar issues exist for all of my pages in this site. Each page has a similar layout associated with it (not yet very DRY).

Comment: UPDATE: I am now using rvm to manage my ruby environments. I restored my website from backup and confirmed that it works under ruby 1.8.7 and rails 3.0.3. As soon as I update to rails 3.0.10 and keep ruby 1.8.7 it breaks the web site. Baffling...

Comment: I figured out the source of the problem. I am using the Cells gem. It had been working fine until the upgrade. Now when I remove the lines that call for this gem to be used, the problem goes away. I have submitted an issue with apotonik[link](https://github.com/apotonick/cells/issues/140). Here is the code in question `<%= render_cell :video_feature, :display, :movies => @movies %>`

Comment: Ok. This was a bug in my software that worked under 3.0.3, but caused the reported problem under later versions of rails/ruby for some reason. The issue is that I was not passing an argument to my method in my cells controller. So instead of `def display` it should have been `def display(quote)` Thank you Nick Sutterer for your kind help to this newbie! Cells is awesome!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is closed. Answer is that Cells controller methods need to have arguments passed to them.

In my cells controller I should have had a method such as:

```
def display(quote)
   @quote = Quote.first

  render
end
```

Instead what I had (and worked under ruby 1.8.7 and rails 3.0.3) was:

```
 def display
   @quote = Quote.first

  render
end
```

My Bug Close! Special thank you to Nick Sutterer who patiently assisted me with this newbie bug!